# Microsoft Malicious Removal Tool slowing down Windows updates?

Tags: windows, performance, download, installation, windows-update

I was just downloading and installing updates it seemed really slow.
It did progress but slowly.

Finally I thought that is there anything happening.
I opened up task manager to see what is happening (if).
Malicous Removal tool was to biggest resource hog and decided to end that task.

Boom, Windows updates took a sprint and everything completed in matter of seconds.
Could this be Malicous Removal tool or was it just luck?

Answer (score 0):

Malicious Software Removal tool appears in Windows Update. This tool removes some malware from Windows systems, particularly those systems without antivirus programs installed.

If you are using Solid Antivirus you wont require MSRT. You can disable MSRT by making changes in Registry and Task Scheduler.

MSRT takes lots of RAM and CPU resource. It need to be scanned each and every files check malicious software or files available.

Which Version of windows are you using now.

Comment: Hi! Windows 7 Pro 64bit. My question was that does MSRT really check all of Windows/Ms own files too? Which makes the update process slower than slow?

Comment: Once a month, a new version of the Malicious Software Removal tool appears in Windows Update. It will not impact your Windows updates. I think when you were installing update meantime MSRT was running in background.

Comment: You shouldn’t need to worry about this tool. Set Windows to automatically install updates, or have Windows alert you to updates and install it along with the other new security updates when they appear every month. The tool will check your computer in the background and stay silent if everything is fine. It will not impact your Update Speed. This will not happen every time when you run the updates.